# JavaScript not picking up the onclick event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have two buttons as:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="one()" />
<input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="two()" />
```

Their definitions in the `script.js` is as

```
 function one() {
     alert("Submit is called");
 }
 function two() {
     alert("Clear is called");
 }
```

Here `one()` is getting picked up but not `two()`

What could be the issue?

Comment: When i run it, I can see both the alerts. Have a look at console. I think there is some error in your js code after function one() in script.js file. You will be able to see the error (if any) in the console.

Comment: Both alerts show for me as well: http://jsfiddle.net/9v4C6/1/

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the second button was calling

```
<input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="click()" />
```

Changing the name from `click()` fixed it.